# Error in my code: Find unique elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I was trying to write the code to find the unique elements of an ArrayList via two loops. items is the list contains elements and duplicates and uniqueitems contains one copy of each.
eg:

- items: bread, cheese, milk, bread, chips, tea, cheese, bread
- uniqueitems: bread, cheese, milk, chips, tea

Here is the code:

```
uniqueitems.add(items.get(0));
for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
{
    count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<uniqueitems.size();j++)
    {
        if(items.get(i).equals(uniqueitems.get(j)))
        {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        n++;
        uniqueitems.add(items.get(n));

    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out my mistake.

Comment: Override equals() and hashcode() methods of your item object.

Comment: Does it work? If not, what ist the error?

Comment: Sorry, Nambari, didn't get that.

Comment: Tichodroma: The output array uniqueitems still contains multiple copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
uniqueitems.add(items.get(n));
```

If `items.get(i)` hasn't been found, then you should add that element in the `uniqueitems`:

```
uniqueitems.add(items.get(i));
```

Don't use that `n` variable.

Also, check if your `equals` method works as expected.

And, if this isn't a homework and your class already overrides `equals` and `hashCode` methods, then you may use this one-line approach:

```
List<YourClass> uniqueItems = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(items));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
uniqueitems.add(items.get(0));
for(int i=1;i<items.size();i++){
    if(!uniqueitems.contains(items.get(i))){
        uniqueitems.add(items.get(i));
    }
}
```

list.contains(Object o) returns true if o is in list

Google is a programmer's friend, try not to re-write methods that already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than write your own code, there's a much simpler and more robust solution: use a **set** data structure. A set, by definition, can only contain unique elements, i.e., no duplicates.

Java has several implementations of the Set interface. I'd suggest using java.util.HashSet. Essentially, you instantiate a HashSet from your ArrayList (which automatically discards duplicates) then extract another ArrayList from the set you just created. That array will contain only the unique elements of your original array.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to say that it's literally a 2-line solution. In the first line you instantiate a HashSet with your ArrayList instance. In the second line you instantiate another ArrayList instance by calling a method on the HashSet instance you created in line 1. And that's it. You now have the distinct entries from your original array in this new array.

Comment: That solution is covered in my answer, and it's a 1-line solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, I was trying to get the OP to do some learning on his own rather than give him the complete answer on a platter. You know, teach a man how to fish and all... :)

Comment: Yes, but this question is asking for a fish, literally :)

Comment: Her. But yeah, Luigi gave the answer in one sentence. And writing your code is always preferred over someone else writing it for you. Though of course learning something new is always helpful.